# ¿Cómo lanzar una notificación con un tono personalizado en Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications, mediaplayer

estoy intentando levantar una `notificación` con `NotificationManager` haciendo un `NotificationCompat.Builder` para crear la misma, lo que sucede es que al momento en que aparezca dicha `notificacion` debe sonar un tono, que establecí por medio de la capeta `raw` con `MediaPlayer` cuando se ejecute el método `Notification`, en la misma notificación cree un botón que le di por nombre `Aceptar`, Al pulsarlo debería detener el tono y lanzarme mi `MainActivity` (Ejecutar la `app`), pero no sucede así, mi notificación se ejecuta solo cuando abro la `app` y cada vez que le doy `Click` al botón `Aceptar` hace un reinicio del `MainActivity` y del tono, como podría solucionar esto?

Aquí esta mi código..

```
public void Notification(){
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.x);
    mp.start();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
        // Configure the notification channel.
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        //notificationChannel.setSound();
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    Intent stopped = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    stopped.setAction("test");
    if (stopped.getAction().equals(stopped)) {
        mp.stop();
    }

    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,1,stopped,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .addAction(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_light, "ACEPTAR", actionPendingIntent)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.circuloleft)
            .setContentTitle("ALERTA!")
            .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/" + R.raw.beeep))
            .setContentText("Se ha detectado una actividad sismica")
            .setContentInfo("SMART");

    notificationManager.notify(/*notification id*/1, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

---

No use `setSound();` por que las formas en que se usa o al menos las que he visto son con tonos o `Ringtones` por defecto de notificaciones de `android`, emplee el `MediaPlayer` para usar el sonido que necesito usar.

Comment: No creo que sea correcto usar el MediaPlayer en esta situación incluso si no esta visible la aplicación y quieres reproducir un sonido este puede no funcionar correctamente. Veo que usas NotificationCompat usa el método setSound().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de tu carpeta raw en resources pon el sonido que quieres reproducir cuando salga la notificacion y solo agrega

```
   Notification notification=new Notification(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now,"Hola",100);

    notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.tu_sonido);
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

antes de `notificationManager.notify()`

Comment: intentare de esta manera a ver que tal se comporta.

Comment: Agregando el setSound solo vibra cuando aparece la notificación pero no suena, el formato de audio que estoy usando es .aac

Comment: el .mp3 tampoco funciona

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar tu archivo de audio ( puede ser .mp3, .aiff, etc) dentro del directorio `/raw` (si no existe lo puedes crear)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma podrías cargar el audio mediante el método [setSound()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#setSound(android.net.Uri,%20android.media.AudioAttributes)) (Suponiendo que el archivo se llama audio.mp3):

```
notificationBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.audio));
```

Comment: Oks esta bien, intentare de esa manera, y les dire en caso de que me funcione, el otro detalle que plantie es que no entiendo por que al ejecutarse la notificacion, le doy click al boton aceptar para detener el sonido y no lo hace, por el contrario se reinicia el metodo y vuelve a aparecer la notificacion, independientemente debo detener el metodo por un pendingIntent pero no se si lo estoy haciendo bien, tengo poca experiencia...

Comment: Agregando el setSound que me planteaste solo vibra cuando aparece la notificacion pero no suena, el formato de audio que estoy usando es .aac

Comment: tambien utilice un .mp3 y tampoco suena.

Comment: y reproduciste desde tu pc estos archivos, se escuchan?, te sugiero actualices tu pregunta para ver que código realizaste. @DavidVillegas

Comment: Ya actualice el código,  alli lo que anexe fue la linea que me comentaste, pero probé con 2 formatos de audio (.aac y .mp3) pero no suena ninguno, solamente vibra al momento de abrir la notificación